# Obj-C memory management: why doesn't this work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[myWindow addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController release];
```

As I understand, `myWindow` should be retaining `viewController.view` for as long as the window needs it. So why does this cause my app to crash on launch? (commenting out the last line fixes the problem, as expected)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[viewController release];
```

You are releasing `viewController` and not the view. `myWindow` will retain the view that you pass in, but not the view controller itself, which is causing it to be deallocated.

Since `view` is retained by the view controller when it is initialized and then retained by `myWindow` when you add it, I imagine the crash is because of subsequent calls to `viewController` (which will now be deallocated).